# replacement for solaris libraries?

Tags: linux, centos, solaris

i have the below script currently on a host with solaris:

```
TZ=US/Eastern
export ORACLE_SID=P2SCP
HOSTNAME=scp3b
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/local/X11/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/ucblib:/export/home/oracle/OraHome1/lib:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_02/jre/lib/sparc:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk/1.6.0_02/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/ucblib:/export/home/oracle/OraHome1/lib:/usr/sii/sapscp/PP010/JCO:/usr/sii/sapscp/PP010/JAR/instantclient10_2:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_02/jre/lib/sparc:/usr/jdk1.6.0_02/jre/lib/sparc
BannerStylUniquePages=1
NLSPATH=:/usr/lib/nls/%L/%N.cat:/usr/lib/nls/C/%N.cat:/usr/sii/mactive/config/PP010/nls/%N.cat:/usr/sii/mactive/config/PP010/dlgscripts/nls/%N.cat
EDITOR=vi
export ORACLE_HOME=/export/home/oracle/OraHome1
SHLVL=2
GROUP=scp
export HOME=/export/home/scp
TERM=xterm
export PATH=.:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/sii/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sii/mactive:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/ucb:/etc:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/opt/csw/gcc3/bin:/export/home/oracle/OraHome1/bin
```

We are migrating to a new host which has centos linux OS. We want to migrate the above script to the new host with centos. I am looking for replacement libraries for "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and "NLSPATH" variables in the above script. I am new to both solaris and centos OS. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply comment out the LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting which is at best a workaround on Solaris and shouldn't be required anyway with properly compiled programs.

The PATH variable should be adapted, especially by pruning the various directories which are missing and not used under Linux.

Finally, I'm not that familiar with NLSPATH but assuming your script is using programs that make use of catalogs, you might need to adapt NLSPATH here.